# StaticBox leads to segmentation fault error if layout is called

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, wxpython

I wanted to improve my GUI by using StaticBoxes. But since I added one I can't call my layout function without crashing python (Segementation fault; no other Error messages).
The following lines reproduce this error exactly. Did I use StaticBoxes correctly?
What do I need to get it to run properly? I use the nested Sizers frequently
so the layout looks nice ;).

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    '''test frame'''
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        '''Constructor'''
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.box = wx.StaticBox(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, u'input value1')
        self.button_calc = wx.Button(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, label=u'calc_xy')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.calculate, self.button_calc)
        self._layout()

    def _layout(self):
        box_sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.box, wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
        inside_the_box = wx.GridBagSizer()
        box_sizer.Add(inside_the_box, 5, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(box_sizer, (0, 0), (2, 2), wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.button_calc, (2, 0))
        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)

    def calculate(self, event):
        print '5'
        self._layout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainWindow(None, -1, 'test window')
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `self._layout()` in your `__init__` method, and it works corectly for me in there.

Then when you click the button you call `self._layout` again and at that point you are trying to assign `self.box` to a new box_sizer but it is already assigned to a sizer therefore the segfault.